# Chrome on Mac not displaying website correctly

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

I recently started using my Macbook for web development, but I then noticed that it shows my websites that work absolutely fine on windows differently and glitched. There is an example below. Does anyone know why that is and how to fix that?

[On Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeYzn.png)

[On Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNdNz.png)

The code: https://codepen.io/zetaxftw/pen/zYdPvKq

```
            <div class="cool">
            <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
            <h3>Up to date</h3>
            <p>I am always trying to be as up to date with the scripts as possible</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, but with Chrome OS and Windows. What I did to fix it was switch browsers and it worked just fine. You can possibly try switching browsers for a bit, then going back to chrome.

Comment: This means that you had your client-side resources cached, but it is not a necessary cause for this type of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t tell what exactly the problem is, because I too use a MacBook and never had problems with it, but it could be something from the code. I would suggest you look up CSS RESET, its css code that makes your websites more compatible with different search engines